# Use returned values from Function1 into Function 2

Tags: php, function

Hello I have two functions here,the first Function will receive 
 scores of   students,and convert all scores into Grades,I want 
 the second function to receive and assign each grade to
 points(weight). Here  is what I have tried so far

```
   function gradeArray($score) {
     if     ($score >= 70)  return "A";
     elseif ($score >= 50)  return "B";
     elseif ($score >= 40)  return "C";
     else                   return "F";
 }
 function grade($grade) {
 $grade=gradeArray($score);
  if     ($grade == "A")  return "1";
 elseif ($grade == "B")  return "2";
  elseif ($grade =="C")  return "3";
   else                   return "4";
 }

  // scores received from HTML form`

    $scores = array (55, 68, 43, 78);

 //Display result in a tabular form
     echo "<table border='1'><th>Score</th><th>Grade</th>";


     foreach ($scores as $score) {
    echo "<tr><td>$score</td><td>" . gradeArray($score) . "</td>
     <td>" .       grade($grade) . "</td></tr>";

      }

      echo "</table>";
```

---

intended output

```
      Score  Grade       Points
      55        B            2
      68        B            2
      43        C            3
      78        A            1
```

After running above code, i get the following errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: grade in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST.php 
>            on  line 24
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: score in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST.php
>             on line 10

Despite of the errors uncounted ,still I get the following results

```
    Score   Grade       Points
     55     B            4
     68     B            4
     43     C            4
     78     A            4
```

where did I go wrong?,Help please , i am very junior at php programing

Comment: And your question is ... ? The code shown here looks like it works. It is very inefficient, but it looks like it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: The code doesnot produce expected points/weight per score sir-BartFriederichs

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the errors and expected results from the code block. It makes the question hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Either use the score as base for both method calls, then use:

```
-function grade($grade) {
+function grade($score) {
 $grade=gradeArray($score);
(...)
 echo "<tr><td>$score</td><td>" . gradeArray($score) . "</td>
-<td>" .       grade($grade) . "</td></tr>";
+<td>" .       grade($score) . "</td></tr>";
```

Or use the the returned grade again (better, as it calls gradeArray() only once)

```
 function grade($grade) {
-$grade=gradeArray($score);
(...)
-echo "<tr><td>$score</td><td>" . $grade = gradeArray($score) . "</td>
+echo "<tr><td>$score</td><td>" . ($grade = gradeArray($score)) . "</td>
 <td>" .       grade($grade) . "</td></tr>";
```

It would be even better if you get `$grade` and `$weight` right after your opening `foreach` and use the variables instead of method calls in your templating code.

Comment: Thank you Sir-clemens321 ,you saved my time.Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

you have two problem in you code :

first you have a variable `$grade` that is not initialised.

second in `grade($grade)` function you have a variable named `$score` that is not initialised in the function so to correct that change you code to this :

```
    function gradeArray($score) {
         if     ($score >= 70)  return "A";
         elseif ($score >= 50)  return "B";
         elseif ($score >= 40)  return "C";
         else                   return "F";
     }
     function grade($grade) {
      if     ($grade == "A")  return "1";
     elseif ($grade == "B")  return "2";
      elseif ($grade =="C")  return "3";
       else                   return "4";
     }

      // scores received from HTML form`

        $scores = array (55, 68, 43, 78);

     //Display result in a tabular form
         echo "<table border='1'><th>Score</th><th>Grade</th><th>points</th>";


         foreach ($scores as $score) {
         $grade = gradeArray($score);
        echo "<tr><td>$score</td><td>" . gradeArray($score) . "</td>
         <td>" .       grade($grade) . "</td></tr>";

          }

          echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks sir,I didnt come back on time.It helped a lot .